# An idea of importing an user define python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, structure, python-import, python-packaging

The structure needs for python 3.8+

That x.py contains x class with a 'display' method
[image]

concept one:

> from p_abcd import a as A
>
> ''' call display '''
>
> A.x.x().display()

Got an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "w.py", line 4, in
>
> A.x.x().display()
>
> AttributeError: module 'p_abcd.a' has no attribute 'x'

concept two:

> import p_abcd.a as A
>
> ''' call display '''
>
> A.x.x().display()

Got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import only `.py` files. Not folders.

So you need something like

```
from p_abcd.a import x
x.display()
```